# Cracking the Coding Interview, 6th Edition- Q: 2.2

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

The question is return the kth to last element of a singly linked list. All the proposed solutions are pretty complex, and I don't know why my solution is invalid. Could someone please let me know why?

```
public class CrackTheInterview {


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public static Node kthToLast(Node n, int k) //pass in LinkedList's head node
    {
        int counter = 1;
        while (n.next != null)
        {
            n = n.next;


        }
        //at the end of the while loop, n equals the last node in the LinkedList
        while (counter != k)
        {
            n = n.previous;
            counter++;
        }
        //now node n is the kth node from the end

        return n;
    }
}
```

---

```
class Node
{
    Node next = null;
    Node previous = null;
    int data;

    public Node (int d)
    {
        this.data = d;
    }

}
```

Comment: Aside from the issue pointed out in the answer, the problem statement seems to be incomplete in that it doesn't specify what should happen if the list has fewer than `k` nodes. Your code also does not account for that possibility.

Comment: Well, your `Node` class doesn't abide by the problem description. The problem states you have a `singly-linked list`, and your node has both a `previous` and a `next`. I'm guessing that is what you mean by `solution is invalid`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A singly linked list would not have both `next` and `previous`. You have a doubly linked list, which clearly makes this problem easier.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a copy of that book, so I don't know what complicated solutions might be found in it, but the following two-finger solution seems pretty simple to me, and is not that different from yours aside from using a singly-linked list:

```
/* Returns the kth last node in the list starting at n.
 * If the list is empty (n == null) returns null.
 * If k is <= 1, returns the last node.
 * If k is >= the number of nodes in the list, returns the first node.
 */
public static Node kthToLast(Node n, int k) {
    Node advance = n;
    while (--k > 0 && advance != null) {
        advance = advance.next;
    }
    /* Now advance is k nodes forward of n. Step both in parallel. */
    while (advance != null) {
        advance = advance.next;
        n = n.next;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first solution in the book says:

> Solution #1: If linked list size is known
>
> If the size of the linked list is known, then the kth to last element is the (length - k)th element. We can
> just iterate through the linked list to find this element. Because this solution is so trivial, we can almost be
> sure that this is not what the interviewer intended.

But we can easily find the size of the linked list by one pass! So modifying the OP's question, I ask what is wrong with the following answer?

We use two pointers. Use one to find the size of the linked list, and use the other one to go (size - k) steps.

(Implementation in Python)

```
def kth_to_last(head, k):
    p1 = head
    p2 = head
    counter = 0
    while p1.nxt is not None:   # calculating the size of the linked list
        p1 = p1.nxt
        counter += 1
    for _ in range(counter - k):
        p2 = p2.nxt
    return p2.val
```

Comment: Exactly my thoughts, time complexity O(n) and space O(1), same as the suggested solution right? And simpler to understand, don't see anything wrong with that. Especially if the suggested alternative in the book is recursive approach which seems overkill here.